# What access token should I use to get public feed with facebook api graph on android

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to make an android app that use the api graph and I have serious problems to understand how it works. I only need to retrieve public data and the app has no login so at the beginning I thought that an access token was not necessary. The official documentation is so poor for android developing and no clear enought for beginners but searching anothers stackoverflow posts I discovered that an access token is required and all people say you must use the appid|appsecret combination.

Now I read that this combination shouldn't be in the app, but in the server. But what if I don't have a server?

I would be grateful if you clarify it to me because I think so I want to do a really easy thing and I'm losing my mind.

Comment: You are correct. You have to use an access token. And the App Access Token "appid|appsecret" should not leave the server.

Comment: But I don't have a server. My app calls the API.

Comment: I'm just telling you what is possible.

Comment: But then I'm obliged to have a server? Is a quite simple app, I dont know if it's worth it.  Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: google for "serverless" if you don´t want a real server. aws lambda, for example.

Comment: _"But what if I don't have a server?"_ - then you either make users login to your app with Facebook, so that you can use their user access token ... or you don’t use those features.